# What's the default timeout of using HttpGet and DefaultHttpClient?

Tags: java, android

The code is like below. If I don't set any timeout parameters, what is the default time out for "new DefaultHttpClient().execute(mConnection)"?

```
mConnection = new HttpGet(mURL);
mResponse = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(mConnection);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default connection timeout is around 60-70 seconds depending on the platform. The default read timeout is infinity.